# Creating a slideable navigation bar using Bootstrap for web and mobile devices

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, header

I am using Bootstrap 4.5.0 (both have the css and script from the CDN on my webpage).  I am trying to make a responsive navigation bar header like the Bootstrap website does, which works well for desktop web browsers and mobile devices as well. My goal I am having trouble with is making the navbar list items be slideable/scrollable from left to right and back again when on a mobile device or a small screen.

The Bootstrap header on a small screen works well like:

[image]

So the above snapshot of Bootstraps site on a small window show Home, Documentation, ... to Themes and is slideable left to right and back with the mouse (desktop) or finger (mobile device).

See the snapshot below after pulling Themes to the left:

[image]

I am having trouble accomplishing this with my code and Bootstrap which is shown below:

```
            <header class="navbar navbar-expand navbar-light flex-column flex-md-row bd-navbar" style="background-color: yellow;">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>

                <div class="navbar-nav-scroll">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav bd-navbar-nav flex-row">
                        <li class="nav-item active">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item active">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Start&nbsp;Test</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item active">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Testaaa</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item active">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Testbbb</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item active">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Testccc</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item active">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Testddd</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item active">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Testeee</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>    
                </div>
            </header>
```

Currently my code does not slide at all and I need some help figuring out what I am missing. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have included 2 CSS paths with your code and the sliding effect is working fine. Do you have these 2 paths included?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/assets/css/docs.min.css">
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/assets/css/docs.min.css">

<header class="navbar navbar-expand navbar-light flex-column flex-md-row bd-navbar" style="background-color: yellow;">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

  <div class="navbar-nav-scroll">
    <ul class="navbar-nav bd-navbar-nav flex-row">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Start&nbsp;Test</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Testaaa</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Testbbb</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Testccc</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Testddd</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Testeee</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Thanks. It was the second CSS (docs.css) that I did not have.

Comment: Where in the 4.5 docs does it say to includ that css file? I am looking at quickstart and downloads pages.

Comment: I am actually looking at the source code. Use chrome dev tool to view the source and I found this css file.

Comment: Yeah I was just using their documentation mostly and comparing there site using dev tools too. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here's is the solution.Please run it on mobile view of browser.I have used both **overflow:hidden** and **overflow-x:auto** to make this working.

```css
 .bd-navbar {
 box-shadow: 0 0.5rem 1rem rgba(0, 0, 0, .05), inset 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);

 }
 .bd-navbar .navbar-nav .nav-link.active, .bd-navbar .navbar-nav .nav-link:hover {
 color: white!important;
 background-color: transparent;
 }
 
 @media all and (max-width: 991px) {
  .bd-navbar {
   padding-right: 0.5rem;
   padding-left: 0.5rem;
 }
  .bd-navbar .navbar-nav-scroll {
   max-width: 100%;
   height: 2.5rem;
   margin-top: 0.25rem;
   overflow: hidden;
 }
  .bd-navbar .navbar-nav-scroll .navbar-nav {
   padding-bottom: 2rem;
   overflow-x: auto;
   white-space: nowrap;
   -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
 }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<header class="navbar navbar-expand navbar-light flex-column flex-md-row bd-navbar" style="background-color: yellow;">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>

                <div class="navbar-nav-scroll">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav bd-navbar-nav flex-row">
                        <li class="nav-item active">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item active">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Start&nbsp;Test</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item active">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Testaaa</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item active">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Testbbb</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item active">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Testccc</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item active">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Testddd</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item active">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Testeee</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>    
                </div>
            </header>
```